# blade.php method outputting it's result to the form

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-blade

I am currently designing a website using the Laravel 4.2 framework and twitter bootstrap. I have set up my `master.blade.php` file which presents a navbar at the top of every page.

Basically if the user is logged in I want to display a navbar with different options than if a user is not logged in. Therefore when a user logs in I set the `$_SESSION` variable.

However, when I use `{{session_start();}}` in my master.blade.php file, 1 is outputted to my website. How to fix this?

```
![<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="{{asset('resources/css/bootstrap.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{asset('resources/css/master.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">][1]


@section('head')

    @show
</head>
<body>

{{session_start();}}

@if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">Jordanstown Dive Club</div>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="login">Log In</a></li>
                <li><a href="signup">Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactus">Contact Us</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    @elseif(isset($_SESSION['email']))

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">Jordanstown Dive Club</div>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout">Log Out</a></li>
                <li><a href="BookaDive">Book a Dive</a></li>
                <li><a href="DiveLog">Dive Log</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactus">Contact Us</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endif
```

Comment: Have you tried grabbing session variables without doing that?  I believe Laravel should have set that all up for you already.  You should also be using the Session facade... `@if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))` becomes `@if(!Session::has('email'))`

Comment: Thank you! That worked a treat. I didn't realize that laravel had that functionality built in! @user3158900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{{ function() }} will be translated to PHP echo, function is executed and return value printed.

In Laravel you do not need to use session_start() as Laravel has builtin session management mechanism.

If you want different menu options then you can check if user is logged in and use @if

```
@if(Auth::check())
  link to Logout
@else
  link to login
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you for the response marcus! Still getting used to the framework, so I don't know about all the built in functions yet.

Comment: Great! If you got it working then you can accept the answer to close the question.