# laravel session_start() returning a 1

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

- In laravel blade view i am doing `{{session_start()}}` and it is echoing out a  why is that and how i fix it?
- i heard that laravel has session management already built in and you dont need session_start(). is this true? because when i remove session_start() and try to return a session value it gives me error of undefined value. if it is true. how can i achieve this without a session start. source for this information.

  [blade.php method outputting it's result to the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827235/blade-php-method-outputting-its-result-to-the-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to write {{session_start()}}

From doc:

> There are two primary ways of working with session data in Laravel:
>   the global session helper and via a Request instance

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session